# Problem creating wp categories

Tags: categories

I have a wordpress site and it doesn't let me create categories and tags.

What would be the problem?

[image]

After creating it appears but it doesn't let me save anything in that category and I don't delete or edit it

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What does Termen gol mean? This is a programming stack, if you're just asking for support/help as a user you should go to the .org support forums

Comment: (Could not insert term into database)
cica ar fi vorba de auto increment